# Changing size of matplotlib subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

Is there an easy way to modify this code so that the plots are bigger without changing the scale on the axes?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
%matplotlib inline

a, c = -10, 10                                
x = np.linspace(a,c,100)                         
x = np.array(x)
def y(x): return np.arctan(x)                       

h = 0.0000001                                   

def grad(x,h): return (y(x+h)-y(x))/h          
m = grad(x,h)

plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(121)
plt.plot(x, y(x), 'b')
plt.xlim([a,c])
plt.ylim([min(y(x)),max(y(x))])
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box') 

plt.subplot(122)
plt.plot(x,m,'b')
plt.xlim([a,c])
plt.ylim([min(m),max(m)])
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')

plt.subplots_adjust(wspace = 0.5)
plt.show()
```

[image]

If I get rid of `plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')` the plots come out a decent size but they are not to scale.

Answer (score 6):

The subplots are shrunk such that their aspect is equal. This seems to be desired; and thus it is not really clear what "bigger" refers to.

You can still make the figure larger, e.g.

```
plt.figure(1, figsize=(12,2))
```

and then adjust the margins and spacings using `plt.subplots_adjust`.[image]

You can also let the axes scale and only set the equal aspect to the data,

```
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='datalim')
```

[image]

Finally plotting the subplots beneath each other makes them bigger as well. So you might use `plt.subplot(211)` and `plt.subplot(212)`.[image]